# Using this.store.filter with the ID of the belongs_to model

Tags: ember.js, filter, belongs-to

I'm trying to retrieve all the layouts for a given account.

**/app/models/account.js**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  companyName: DS.attr('string'),
  layouts: DS.hasMany('layout')
});
```

**/app/models/layout.js**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  account: DS.belongsTo('account', { async: true })
});
```

**/app/routes/layouts.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      layouts: this.store.filter('layout', { account_id: 1 }, function(layout) {
        console.log(layout.get('account').content.id);
        return layout.get('account').content.id === 1;
      })
    });
  }
});
```

The console.log line is outputting the ID that I'm expecting (1). In Ember inspector I can see 5 layout models and under 'Belongs To' I can see: `account : <DS.PromiseObject:ember960>`. Clicking that brings up `content : <batmics@model:account::ember600:1>` and clicking that brings up the properties, including the correct ID.

But in my templates `layouts` is empty... and I've no idea why.

Incidentally, `layouts: this.store.find('layout', { account_id: 1 })` works, but I need it to use the filter so that it's an active array.

Comment: What isn't working? Not clear what your problem is..

Comment: Sorry, I've clarified the question

Comment: I'm wondering if your problem could be because the `account` relationship is `async` and maybe it's not loaded at the time the function runs.. But that doesn't line up with the fact that the console logs the correct information.. If you change the filter to simply return `true`, removing the check your doing, does that change the outcome? Do you get the full list of `layout`s?

Comment: I do indeed get a full list of layouts

Comment: Oh.. I think I know what it is.. I'll post an answer

Comment: Answer posted.. Is there a reason for not using something a bit simpler like returning the `account` in your model hook and accessing the layouts in your template via `account.layouts`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ember Data works with all its IDs as strings.

Changing your check to `=== '1'` should get this going for you.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      layouts: this.store.filter('layout', { account_id: 1 }, function(layout) {
        console.log(layout.get('account').content.id);
        return layout.get('account').content.id === '1';
      })
    });
  }
});
```